# How to find Odd or Even numbers in a single Integer in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to solve a problem on how to extract all odd and even numbers in a single Integer.

For example
I input the number `6`:
and it will be stored at `num = scanner.nextInt();`
then the expected answer or output will be:

```
1,3,5
2,4,6
```

I already tried ArrayList but I'm kind of confused.

Here's my code from @LIttle Ancient Forest Kami at codereview:

````
     static ArrayList odds = new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                int[] simpleTable = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

                for (int i: simpleTable) {
                    if (i%2 == 0) {
                        evens.add(i);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(evens);

                for (int i: simpleTable) {
                    if (i%2 != 0) {
                        odds.add(i);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(odds);
    }```

/*

System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
        num = scanner.nextInt();


        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        do{
            array.add(0, num %10);
            num /= 10;
        } while  (num > 0);

        if ((num%2) == 0) {
                  System.out.println(array);
            }
        else
        {
               System.out.println(array);
        }
      } */
````

Comment: What do you mean by an odd or even number being "in" some other integer? As a decimal digit of that integer? A factor of the integer? As any number that's part of a total that add up to that integer?

Comment: What is your exact input and output?

Comment: @Alpha-Centauri 
I want to extract all even and odd number from 6 and print them

odd: 1,3,5 
even: 2,4,6

Comment: @kshetline what i mean is how can i extract and print even numbers and odd numbers from the int num; with scanner, check my /* comment code from

Comment: You've just repeated the same unclear concept using the word "from" instead of the word "in". From part of the code, it looks like you mean the separate digits that comprise a given number. But then when you say you expect the output for the number 6 to be "1,3,5 2,4,6", that sounds like a totally different concept of "in" or "from".

Comment: It seems hes is asking for all integers up and including the given number, separating them by even/odd. Looks like a basic example for a loop with an if inside...

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```java
    public class MyTry {
static ArrayList<Integer> simpleTable = new ArrayList();

static ArrayList<Integer> odd = new ArrayList();
 static ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList();
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   for(int a=0; a<11; a++){
     simpleTable.add(a);

  for (int i : simpleTable){
    if(i%2 == 0){
      even.add(i);
    }else{
      odd.add(i);
    }
  }
  System.out.print(even);
  System.out.print(odd);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I fixed my problem Thank you for your Contribution! here's my answer:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> odds = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList<Integer> evens = new ArrayList();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    int num;


    System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
    num = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Even and Odd numbers between 1 and " + num);

    for(int i=1; i <= num; i++){

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            evens.add(i);
          } else {
            odds.add(i);
          }
        }
        System.out.println(evens);
        System.out.println(odds);

 }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Number: 
12
Printing Even and Odd numbers between 1 and 12
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```